# Построение эффективной CI/CD инфраструктуры с нуля начинающему devops инженеру

Tags: c#, angular2, docker, непрерывная-интеграция, devops

## Предыстория.

На работе встала задача, наше новое приложение, разработанное на asp.net core и Angular по серьёзному развернуть на серверах компании. Инженеров devops нет и не предвидится, поэтому мне как старшему разработчику придётся осваивать и это направление т.к. команда и так не большая - всего 4 человека. В общем, проблема возникла на стадии планирования.

Сейчас в компании используются две независимые гальванически не связанные сети для интернета и для внутренней подсети. Вся инфраструктура (1с и прочее) находятся именно в локальной сети без доступа из вне. Разработчики напротив сидят именно в интернетовском сегменте.

Обдумывая инфраструктуру серверов для публикации и тестирования проекта я обдумывал использовать Docker.(Само приложение будет использовать linux в качестве серверной платформы(nginx для angular, postgresql - db, api на .net core).

### Небольшая выжимка информации.

- Windows; Visual studio 2017 для разработки API; Visual studio code для Angular; GitLab на внутренем интернет сервере;
- API написано с использованием ASP.NET Core 2; Клиент на Angular 4; DB - postgresql;
- Разработчики находятся в отдельной сети от места развертывания приложения;
- Сервера с приложением будут в локальной сети без доступа к интернету;
- В качестве базовой платформы будет использоваться ProxMox в локальной сети;

### Структура получившаяся на мой взгляд.

[image: Структура получившаяся на мой взгляд]

Вот только есть несколько проблем (собственно вопросов):

- Обновление пакетов NPM(в качестве пакетного менеджера используется Yarn) и NuGet. Добавление новых пакетов.  Вроде, как и для nuget и для Yarn можно делать offline зеркала, но как поддерживать в них актуальность? И есть ли возможность обновлять/добавлять пакеты используя Git? м.б. кто-то сталкивался с этим?
- Есть ли вообще смысл от Гипервизора и виртуальных машин? Или в данной ситуации лучше на одной физической машине развернуть всё? Есть ли плюс поддержки виртуальных машин (в будущем планировалось объединить несколько серверов в кластер и добавить репликацию с резервированием)?
- Возможно ли что я иду в неправильном направлении и все мои идеи и мысли в корне не верны? Будет ли мне потом мучительно больно при работе со всем этим? :)
- Где вообще можно почитать об организации такой структуры с нуля?

Возможно кто-то подскажет как лучше организовать весь этот процесс CI/CD. Для меня это первый опыт в этом направлении и всё хочется сделать правильно (на сколько это возможно)) ведь мне самому придётся работать со всей этой структурой и как разработчику и как devops.

Comment: Возможно кстати, я выбрал неправильный стек технологий? В качестве альтернативы GitLab CI/CD  я рассматривал TeamCity и Octopus Deploy. Только к сожалению так и не понял как собрать образы docker compose 
 и залить их на docker registry с использованием этих инструментов. Также возможно я зря думаю о docker как silver bullet и для моего кейса он не подходит. Очень хочется услышать мысли умных людей по этому поводу.

Comment: есть подписка на TFS или vsts?

Comment: @ЮрийБезруков если я правильно помню, нам доступен дистрибутив tfs по подписке Visual Studio Professional

Comment: Если у разработчиков есть доступ к интернету, то мне кажется, было бы разумно осуществлять сборку именно в этой подсети. На выходе получаем готовый образ докера, который пробрасываем в подсеть без интернета. В любом случае что-то прокидывать придется: исходники, npm/nuget пакеты, сборки или же образ docker. По мне так последнее удобнее всего. Вообще TFS сейчас очень удобный вариант. В 2017 версии появились еще и локальные npm и nuget галереи.

Comment: а можно поинтересоваться, как решили свои задачи? и ещё (чуть не по теме), почему ангуляр пишете в VS Code?

Comment: @Anatol Я не успел нормально поднять инфраструктуру т.к. через некоторое время перешел на другое место работы. Тут у меня полностью всё в интернете и по этому у меня TeamCity собирает Docker образы и заливает их в локальное Registry. ссылка Следит за Image и обновляет по надобности. VS Code до сих пользуюсь для быстрого редактирования мелочей. Ранее использовал VSCode просто как новичок в FrontEnd. Сейчас пользуюсь WebStorm для Angular и Rider для .Net. Переезд на JB продукты - чисто вкусовщина. Ну и немного повлияло то что ноутбук у меня  MacBook.

Comment: спасибо, любопытно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Обновление пакетов NPM(в качестве пакетного менеджера используется
>   Yarn) и NuGet. Добавление новых пакетов. Вроде, как и для nuget и для
>   Yarn можно делать offline зеркала, но как поддерживать в них
>   актуальность? И есть ли возможность обновлять/добавлять пакеты
>   используя Git? м.б. кто-то сталкивался с этим?

Большинство пакетных менеджеров могу скачивать репозитории по ssh / git. 
`yarn install git+ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<package>.git`. С **nuget** видимо только репозитории. Пока это не проблема, а **будущая возможная оптимизация**, по уменьшению трафика и **увеличению скорости билдов**. **Спокойно игнорируем на этом этапе.**

> Есть ли вообще смысл от Гипервизора и виртуальных машин? Или в данной
>   ситуации лучше на одной физической машине развернуть всё? Есть ли плюс
>   поддержки виртуальных машин (в будущем планировалось объединить
>   несколько серверов в кластер и добавить репликацию с резервированием)?

**Смысл есть - изоляция**, но и overhead. Как плюс **gold image**, в котором уже все готово, нужно только залить весь стек (**docker stack deploy**).
Вполне можно ужиться и на одном, более рисковый путь.
Для кластера - **docker-swarm + glusterfs** / edge fs / etc (для **overlay volumes**).

> Возможно ли что я иду в неправильном направлении и все мои идеи и
>   мысли в корне не верны? Будет ли мне потом мучительно больно при
>   работе со всем этим? :)

**Направление верное.** Мучительно ли? - Да, как и всё новое.
Мой пример - **docker-swarm** около месяца (две из них **auto letsencrypt** + **nginx**).
Просто потому что выбрал инструмент, который знал. После на **Traefik** сделал за два дня.

**Автоматизировать, нужно постепенно.** Сделать **CI**. Deploy ручной, но c одной командой. По началу даже так ускорится процесс (**Fail Fast**).

Ни слова не упомянули о **конфигурационной менеджменте**. Тут **Ansible** в [помощь](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-repo-for-startup). По ссылке мой опыт автоматизации деплоя на **swarm cluster**, а так же структура, которая позволит быстро добавить новые сервисы и задеплоить.

Конечно есть нюансы, типа нельзя воспользоваться deploy script, пока нету **registry**. Или workflow c [множеством docker-compose.*.yml файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1007486/251778). Плюс полная докеризация ([как пример](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/dockemacs)) или [DevSecOps](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/dockemacs/blob/master/.travis.yml).

> Где вообще можно почитать об организации такой структуры с нуля?

**Подписаться на DevOps рассылки**, настроить **google alerts** по темам (**docker**, **container**, etc). Повышать кругозор. Накладывать свои знания на свою реальность. **И много экспериментировать.**