# Как запустить свое Docker образ на другой машине?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Я новичок в docker, да и вообще в программировании. Подскажите пожалуйста. 
Ситуация следующая. Я написал блог на Ruby on rails и решил этот блог поместить в Docker образ. 
Создал в папке с проектом:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /usr/src/myapp/
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp/
COPY Gemfile /usr/src/myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /usr/src/myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /usr/src/myapp/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

    services:
      db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
          - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
          - .:/myapp
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
          MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      web:
        build: .
        command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b "0.0.0.0"
        env_file:
          - .env
        volumes:
          - .:/myapp
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
          - db
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
    volumes:
      db_data:
```

И файл .env:

```
DATABASE_USER=root
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_HOST=db
```

После этого собрал проект: `docker-compose up`

И всё работает.

**ВОПРОС: если полученный образ загрузить на dockerhub, как его потом запустить на другой машине  с помощью docker-compose или как нибудь иначе?**

Образ на DockerHub: https://hub.docker.com/r/igortyutyunov/lightblog

Answer (score 0):

> ВОПРОС: если полученный образ загрузить на dockerhub, как его потом
>   запустить на другой машине с помощью docker-compose или как нибудь
>   иначе?

Docker-compose достаточно. Необходимо описать **image и build options** в отдельном файле (**docker-compose.staging.yml**), лучше использовать названия `environment`.
Здесь описываем сервисы, которые будем билдить (**чужие образы игнорируем**).

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  web:
    image: "$REGISTRY/${WEB_SERVICE}:${WEB_SERVICE__VERSION}"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

В `.env` добавить:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=web # одинаковое название независимо от папки
REGISTRY=igrik007 # dockerhub или example.com (private registry)
WEB_SERVICE=web_service
WEB_SERVICE__VERSION=1.0.0
```

Теперь запускаем build и push в dockerhub:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.staging.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.staging.yml push
```

Образ зальётся, на другой машине выполнить:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.staging.yml pull
```

> Для `deploy` развернуть `docker-swarm`, если есть свой сервер, полезно
>   будет для обучения. Или развернуть на `heroku`.

Как пример опишу свой `workflow`.

**.env** - только переменные для docker-compose, не в `.gitignore` (название проекта и сервисов, версии)

**docker-compose.yml** - описываю базовые опции (image, ports, command, environment)
Переменные подставляюся во время деплоя с `ansible`.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  example:
    image: "${REGISTRY}/${EXAMPLE_SERVICE}:${EXAMPLE_SERVICE__VERSION}"
    command: sh -c './wait-for pg:5432 -- python server.py'
    ports:
      - 8080
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: 'pg'
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_DB: '{{ services.example.db.name }}'
      POSTGRES_USER: '{{ services.example.db.user }}'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '{{ services.example.db.password }}'
```

**docker-compose.development.yml** - пишу все опции, перезаписываем переменные (volumes, debug)

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  example:
    image: "$REGISTRY/${EXAMPLE_SERVICE}:${EXAMPLE_SERVICE__VERSION}-development"
    command: sh -c './wait-for pg.example_net:5432 -- python server.py'
    build:
      context: .
    networks:
      - net
    depends_on:
      - example__migrator
    volumes:
      - .:/home/example
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
      POSTGRES_HOST: pg.example_net
      POSTGRES_DB: example_development
      POSTGRES_USER: example
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
```

**docker-compose.override.yml** - для development `ln -s docker-compose.development.yml docker-compose.override.yml`, чтобы запускать также одной командой `docker-compose up`.

**docker-compose.{staging, production, etc}.yml** - опции нужные только для build

**docker-compose.swarm.yml** - дописываем сеть, healthcheck, volumes, depends_on, etc

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  example:
    networks:
      - net
    healthcheck:
      test: 'nc -z localhost 8080 > /dev/null 2>&1 || exit 1'
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

Получаем разбитую конфигурацию на кусочки. Для деплоя написан скрипт который собирает эти кусочки в один.

`docker-compose -f file -f file config > docker-compose.yml`.

Затем как `ansible template`, поставив секреты, заливается на удаленный сервер и деплоится.

`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml example --with-registry-auth`

Секреты зашифрованы с `ansible-vault` в `{{ environment }}.yml` либо `{{ host }}.yml`

[Подробнее на github](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-repo-for-startup)