# Что делать, если несколько docker-compose зависят от одного mysql?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Не смог сформулировать вопрос лучше.

В общем такая ситуация:

есть веб приложение, которое использует **nginx**, **php**, **mysql**,

есть некоторые сервисы в виде бинарников, которые тоже используют тот же mysql(данные)

соответственно это 2 разных docker-compose, которые должны работать автономно друг от друга.

В голове 3 варианта:

1. из ДК(docker-compose) сервисов ссылаться на мускуль, который в вебе, но тогда ДК сервисов теряет автономность;
2. в ДК сервисов добавить еще один контейнер с мускулем, в котором будет подключен volume с теми же данными, что и в вебе - вроде бы лучше, но запускается 2 инстанса мускуля, что тоже не очень. А если в будущем там будут еще redis, rabbitmq, etc...
3. В виде отдельного ДК, но опять же проблемы автономности.

Более ничего не придумал. Может кто-то сталкивался с похожей ситуацией и знает как было бы лучше?

P.S. с докером дружу недавно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> соответственно это 2 разных docker-compose, которые должны работать автономно друг от друга.

Почему должны? Не обязательно.

Для разработки можно все объединить в один docker-compose (запускать через `docker-compose run service`). Или линкануть `docker-compose.services.yml` на `docker-compose.override.yml`.

**Только, если сервисы написанные на другом языке (другой git repository c кодом), советую делить на стеки (много docker-compose файлов).**

*Для продакшена использую docker-swarm, который позволяется deploy через docker-compose файлы. Более подробно [о разбиении docker-compose файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1007091/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-docker-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5/1007486#1007486).*

Да, появляется зависимость как в development, так и в production, которая заключается **в объединение по сети**. Ничего не мешает запустить стек, который зависит от другой сети (предварительно её создав).

Пример зависимости:

Каждому web приложению нужен [`reverse-proxy`](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/sanic-simple-api/blob/7607408ce748fc2f605a7ca1d7fbb40dfea3f6f0/docker-compose.swarm.yml#L20-L23), но он не входит в сам стек приложения.

Просто используем его сеть (production). Появляется зависимость, но логичная, что каждому web приложения нужен reverse-proxy (ssl, балансировка, etc). Но для разработки - это не требуется.

> Что делать, если несколько docker-compose зависят от одного mysql?
>
> в ДК сервисов добавить еще один контейнер с мускулем, в котором будет подключен volume с теми же данными, что и в вебе - вроде бы лучше, но запускается 2 инстанса мускуля, что тоже не очень. А если в будущем там будут еще redis, rabbitmq, etc...

Выше я писал, что нужно делить на стеки. Парадокс, в том, что удобно разрабатывать маленькими стеками, но в продакшене начинаются проблемы с зависимостью.

Как избежать:

- Просто во время деплоя объединять в один большой стек (общая сеть)
- Раздельно деплоить. Дублирование mysql контейнеров с общей volume (nfs, etc).
- Раздельно деплоить. Кластер mysql (master-slave)

Первый вариант проще, c точки зрения поддержки, но есть затраты на [скрипт деплоя](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-repo-for-startup/blob/master/deploy#L7-L26) и его поддержку.

> В виде отдельного ДК, но опять же проблемы автономности.

Базу, считаю зависимостью, а не сервисом. Соотвественно, она принадлежит либу web, либо services.

Comment: Большое спасибо!